# Can mythological names be trademarked and become associated with an entity (eg. a company)?

Tags: trademark

Can the names of creatures, deities (gods), locations, etc. be trademarked and become associated with a specific entity (so it receives protection against dilution)?

Comment: Simple answer: Nike..

Comment: I looked up “Thor” (assuming a movie and comic book character might be trademarked) and there are dozens of trademarks in all different areas. So I guess you can’t create a movie character or a power drill named “Thor” but other things will be open. Probably weaker than “Nike”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example, [search the USPTO trademark database](https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/search) for "[Deimos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deimos_(deity))."

See also "[Lamborghini Trademark for 'Deimos' May Point to Future Model](https://www.caranddriver.com/news/a18738574/lamborghini-trademark-for-deimos-may-point-to-future-model/)".

Comment: I cannot believe you missed Nike or Amazon.

Comment: I suppose many people won’t even know that “Nike” is a Greek goddess.